# How can I make the JQuery addon "Rounded Corners" work? (or suggest a better option)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having problems getting the JQuery Library "Rounded Corners" to work in IE. All I want to do is simulate border-radius on a div in Internet Explorer. I have gotten the addon to work in Firefox, but I think that's because this addon takes advantage of that CSS property. I have also gotten it to work in IE, but only on basic DIVs.

Here is the addon's home page: http://jquery.malsup.com/corner/

Here is the code:

### CSS

```
<style>
#mydiv { /*basic CSS for the DIV*/
    border: 1px solid #76B4EA;
    border-bottom: none;
    box-shadow: inset -10px 10px 30px #e0e0e0, 2px -2px 1px #707070;
    background: #fff;
    width: 200px;
    height: 80px;
    margin-top: 21px;
    z-index: 3;
    margin-left:2px; 
    position: absolute
}
#ie-shadow { /*code for a cross-browser shadow*/
    display: none;
}
</style>
<!--[if lte IE 8]>/*more code for the cross-browser shadow*/
<style>
#ie-shadow {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 17px;
    left: 2px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 80px;
    z-index: 1;
    background: #000;
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(PixelRadius='2', MakeShadow='true', ShadowOpacity='0.40');

}
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

### HTML

```
<div id="mydiv"></div>
<div id="ie-shadow">&nbsp;</div>
```

### Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.corner.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#mydiv').corner("rounded top 10px keep cc:transparent");
</script>
```

Comment: why doe your code say #logo and the HTML NOT say that?

Comment: Sorry, I was in a hurry. In the actual project, it's logo. :)

Comment: I fixed it; it now says `#mydiv`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm going to suggest a better option: PIE.htc.

Download it here: http://css3pie.com/

**USAGE**

Extract the PIE.htc file to your root directory. In your CSS, you can do the following:

```
.round-em {
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  behavior: url('PIE.htc');
}
```

**NOTE:** The location of the PIE.htc is relative to the HTML file, NOT the CSS file. Also, you may ONLY use the shorthand of `border-radius`. You cannot specify `border-top-left-radius`, for example, when using the hack for IE.

You can take it a step further by adding an IE conditional (PIE.htc does not play nice with IE9+):

```
.round-em {
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

`<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    .round-em {
      behavior: url('PIE.htc');
    }
<![endif]-->`

**EDIT**

Since you cannot load the PIE.htc script across domains, you can use PIE.js. Here is the link: http://css3pie.com/documentation/pie-js/

There is a hosted version available here: http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/css3pie/1.0beta5/PIE.js

**HOW TO USE PIE.JS**

First, call the script via an IE conditional:

`<!--[if lt IE 9]>`
`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/css3pie/1.0beta5/PIE.js"></script>`
`<![endif]-->`

Next, use jQuery to iterate through each of the elements that have `round-em` as a class. Then, use the `PIE.attach` method and pass in the `this` context as a parameter.

```
$(function() {
  if (window.PIE) {
    $('.rounded').each(function() {
      PIE.attach(this);
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: I really want to avoid HTC because I can't host any files, and I don't think my server can do it.

Comment: It's a file like any other. If you can publish an HTML file, you can publish PIE.htc.

Comment: Actually, I am embedding the HTML. It's a bit hard to explain, but think Myspace.

Comment: Ahhhh! I don't want to think about Myspace :) There is also a PIE.js which you may want to look into. I'll append it to my answer.

Comment: OK, this is perfect. Two more questions, however. First: is it hosted online anywhere? Second: How exactly do I use the JS version?

Thanks

Comment: Sweet, I found a hosted version of it here: http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/css3pie/1.0beta5/PIE.js

Comment: Could you please show me here: http://jsfiddle.net/by2pz/4/? I am having some problems. I know it's probably something really dumb, but I am fairly new to JS.